# Capture what user types in other applications

Tags: android, privacy

Hey before today I thought there is no way to capture what user types in other applications based on my searches in stack overflow an other sites but today I saw an application that can offer emojis based on what you type in social applications. How is that possible?
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.dango.emoji.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess they internally use an `AccessibilityService`.

This kind of service is intended primarily to assist people with disabilities (something like TalkBack for example). When registered, this service receives `AccessibilityEvents`. These events are fired for example when the user interacts with the device or the displayed content changes. Internally, they contain a tree of `AccessibilityNodeInfos` which contain detailed information about the view hierarchy displayed on the screen.

Therefore the app can traverse the `AccessibilityNodeInfo` tree and extract the text that user enters.

You can read more about `AccessibilityServices` [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html).

Bottom line: be careful when you install apps that require the accessibility permission, as they may pose a serious security risk.